# Using multiple go versions while debugging with GoLand

Tags: go, goland

Using [Go's documentation](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install) on managing Go installs, I have got two versions of Go on my system:

```sh
$ go version
go version go1.16.13 linux/amd64

$ go1.17 version
go version go1.17 linux/amd64
```

1.16 installed using Fedora's `dnf` and 1.17 using `go install golang.org/dl/go1.17@latest; go1.17 download` (I get it that latest 1.17 is 1.17.6, but that's OK for my purpose.)

In GoLand, I would like to use go1.17 to debug without modifying the system settings as a whole to use go1.17 every time I run a go command. I tried setting `GOBIN=/home/<username>/go/bin/go1.17` in the Environment section of "Run/Debug Configurations", but that doesn't work (I'm not sure if it should.)

Is it possible to use a different Go version for debugging while using GoLand? How?

Answer (score 3):

You can add your `1.16.13` Golang to the GoRoot setting from this path: `settings/Go/GOROOT`

see this picture
[image]

after that, you can select The target version that you want to test. just need to select between 1.17 or 1.16 in this setting.

unfortunately, I didn't find any easier solution.